# Inject ServiceLocator in Validator

Tags: zend-framework2

How can I inject the "normal" ServiceManger into a custom validator used for REST calls (Use without Form). ZF 2.2.7 Used to inject an instance of external library into an validator.

I have tried the following, and nothing works:

- Inject it with the ValidationPluginManager, service not found
- Inject it via factory, factory will not be loaded in validator chain
- Inject it via validator options, not possible because the "ServiceManager" is an instance of ValidationPluginManager with the asme result as mentioned in #1

Is there any concept how to solve this problem, or do i have to give up and link all libraries statically?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a discussion on github about a somewhat similar problem [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4219). They suggested to use `Zend\Form\FormAbstractServiceFactory` and tinker with dependencies there (weierophinney before closing the topic).

In your post you mention you are not using a `form` did you mean you are not using the form in a classic kind of way or are you bypassing the whole form in particular?

It simply seems off to me to use a validator if there isn't a `form` present. Could you elaborate more on that?

EDIT: To my understanding zf2 requires that your input filters have form elements like 'inputs' etc. You did not post any code and I simply do not know if/or your able to bypass this somehow. I still do not understand why you'd still want to use validators in combination of input filters. I would simply skip the input filters and write the custom validator.

My personal preferences is to write factories instead of anonymous functions within `module.php` files. But this also could work the anonymous function way.

I would then simply resolve the dependencies within the customValidatorFactory and get the factory within my controller or whatever place I would need it.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use CustomValidator;    

class CustomValidatorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create Service Factory
     * 
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $sm = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $customService = $sm->get('Application\Service\Geocoding');

        $validator= new CustomValidator();
        $validator->setCustomService($service);

        return $validator;
    }
}
// CustomValidator.php
class CustomValidator extends Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator
    {    
    public function setCustomService($service)
    {
       $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $customService = $this->service;
        if ($customService->customMethod() == true) {
           return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
}

//module-config.php
 'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'custom\ValidatorFactory' => 'Namespace\To\CustomValidatorFactory',
    ),
),

//yourController or whatever.php will require access to the service manager
$customValidation = $sm->get('custom\ValidatorFactory');
// should return true or false now
$state = $customValidation->isValid($someValue);
```

Comment: The data is sent via REST to our controller, so I dont need any form, but want to have input filtering and validation on server side. So i do setData and then isValid on the input filter.


The problem is not to instanicate the validator itself, i have a problem to get other services (from the normal ServiceLocator) inside the validator.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I also use factories everywhere. The problem is that zf2 validators can't be located via the normal `ServiceLocator` only via the `ValidationManager` which in turn not know normal services. And this is the way the `InputFilter` work.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested this and have never done with with ValidationPluginManager but works with ControllerManager, FormElementManager etc

```
// GetServiceLocator call should return Instance of ServiceManager
// Then retrieve the service, Yay!
$validationPluginManager->getServiceLocator()->get('SomeService')
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that `getServiceLocator` returns null, also the `$sl` property on the ValidationManager is null of course.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that playing around with this to see if it actually worked. I thought you could create a delegator factory and call setServiceLocator to Service Manager but it is already set at this point. This is a bug in my opinion. Everywhere else the service manager is injected correctly and is available all the way through the application lifecycle. Always neater to use a factory to satisfy the dependency anyway I guess

Comment: Whilst I don't massively agree with having the main service manager injected everywhere. I pretty much never do it in my own classes and always use a factory or delegator factory to handle dependencies. I feel that since the service manager is assigned to $serviceLocator parameter of the ValidatorPluginManager when the service is first created and then later it is null which is not consistent with any other plugin manager that this is kinda of a bug. But +1 for it being sorted in zf3

Comment: Yes I agree. But the curious thing is that I am not able to get a validator via a factory from the ValidationManager. I have a `validators => factories` entry in my module.conf.php, i get the following exception: Plugin of type <MyValidatorFactory> is invalid; must implement Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface